# Streaming music developer service?

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, audio-player

I have an idea for a small project around music discovery. I'm hoping to find a service that has access to a huge collection of music (a la Spotify, Google Play, etc) but doesn't require each user to already have access to that.

Does this sort of service/api exist somewhere? My googling didn't turn up anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial options, but for your project you might consider Radio Reddit. We have a fairly large library of music mostly fun unsigned musicians.

While we haven't officially documented the API and are still under construction, the media APIs work well and are easy to understand. You can look at your tab while browsing music on the site for an example, or email me at brad@radioreddit.com.

Comment: Thanks Brad! I'll look in to it. Do you happen to know where I can get any information about commercial licenses?